# How exactly work this Spring unit test that use a mock object?

Tags: java, spring, junit, mocking, easymock

I am studying for the Spring Core certification and I have some doubts related to the use of the **mock** in JUnit test.

I know that, differently from stubs where I have to implement an interface to create a fake object (my stub), using mock I use a **mocking framework** (as **EasyMock**) that generate for me a mock object used in my tests.

So the steps to testing using mock are the following:

1. Use a mocking library to generate a mock object that **implements the dependent interface on-the-fly**
2. Record the mock with expectations of how it will be used for a scenario: **what methods will be called** and **what values to return**
3. Exercise the scenario
4. Verify mock expectations were met

So for example I can have the following test class:

```
import static org.easymock.classextensions.EasyMock.*;

public class AuthenticatorImplTests {

    // 1) Implementation of AccountRepository interface is created:
    private AccountRepository accountRepository = createMock(AccountRepository.class);

    private AuthenticatorImpl authenticator = new AuthenticatorImpl(accountRepository);

    @Test 
    public void validUserWithCorrectPassword() {

        // 2) RECORDING: What behavior to expect?
        expect(accountRepository.getAccount(“lisa”)).andReturn(new Account(“lisa”, “secret”));

        // Recording Playback (???)
        replay(accountRepository);

        // 3) Excercise the scenario:
        boolean res = authenticator.authenticate(“lisa”, “secret”);
        assertTrue(res);

        // 4) Verify mock expectations were met
        verify(accountRepository);
    }
}
```

Ok, there is something that are very clear for me but there are some other things that I can't understand.

What happens?

It seems to me that:

1. It is created a runtime mock implementation of the dependency represented by the **AccountRepository** interface needed to test the **AuthenticatorImpl** class as unit.
2. My mock is recorded with expectations of how it will be used for a specific scenario, in the previous example the expectations are: 1) **METHOD CALLED:** getAccount("Lisa") and **RETURNED VALUES OF THE CALLED METHOD:** a new Account object created passing "Lisa" and "secret" as constructor parameters

Ok, so untill now it seems to me that it have dinamically created a specific mock object and the **Account** object (with setted values) that I expect to retrieve calling the **getAccount("Lisa")** method on this object. Is it right?

Now I have the first doubt: what exactly do the following line?

```
replay(accountRepository);
```

Is it call only to make the Mock object available ?

1. Then I perform the test on the of the **authenticate()** method of the **AuthenticatorImpl** class. If the **assertTrue(res);** return me a "green bar" the test is passed.
2. Verify mock expectations were met by the line:

   verify(accountRepository);

Ok...but exactly what this line do? Because I think that what say if the unit test is passed ("green bar") or not passed ("red bar") is the result of the previous assert, why the test end callung this **verify()** method and passing it the mocked object? what do this method?

Tnx

Answer (score 2):

Using EasyMock you usually do the following: first of all create your mock. Then record expected behaviour and if needed returns/exceptions/... then you put your mock into replay mode. I.e. you tell EasyMock that you're done recording and now if you call a method on your mock you actually want the recorded behaviour.  Then you'll invoke the business logic to test. After that you do your asserts and make sure that the expected behaviour (calling of your mocks methods) was correctly performed by your business logic by calling verify.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I have the first doubt: what exactly do the following line?

```
replay(accountRepository);
```

There are 2 stages in the life of a mock object:

1. setting expectations
2. being exercised

The `replay(mockObject)` invocation moves the mock from one stage to the other.

> Because I think that what say if the unit test is passed ("green bar")
>   or not passed ("red bar") is the result of the previous assert, why
>   the test end callung this verify() method and passing it the mocked
>   object? what do this method?

This is wrong. The **assertTrue(res)** alone is not enough to tell whether the test has been successful.

Using your example, imagine that the authenticator returns the expected result when being  invoked like `authenticator.authenticate(“lisa”, “secret”)` but without internally invoking the repository. Should the test pass? Not, and that's what you check with the `replay(accountRepository)`.